Add Powerpoint presentation to SharePoint intranet portal dynamically
Hello Community Members!
I have a scenario to display the ppt in the SharePoint Intranet portal. However, whenever the user deletes and adds the new ppt file, the latest file should be displayed dynamically in the portal. How can we achieve this?
By using File and Media webpart, we can only display the ppt by changing manually everytime.
Thankyou!
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Have you tried Gallery webpart set to show 1?

No, but it is possible to display the file dynamically?

Gallery will only display images

My bad, we made a custom webpart also named gallery and I had the two mixed up. By default, what you are asking is not possible. You can get the effect via power automate, though. Step 1) make a folder and .ppt file you're going to link to. This one is default 2) Any time new ppt file is added to the library, overwrite the "default" file in the folder with it by using power automate.

Don't delete the PPT. Instead, use a file name like "Portal.pptx" and when a new PPT needs to replace the current one, overwrite it with exactly the same file name. The next time the page is loaded, it will still fetch the PPT called "Portal.pptx", whose content is now different.
The version history will still have the older versions, but you could also store all the different PPT files in a separate folder.
